# Problem with StaticResource AppName

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

```
<StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" 
                   Text="{StaticResource AppName}" 
                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" 
                   Text="Save Info" 
                   Margin="9,-7,0,0" 
                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

The resource "AppName" could not be resolved, any ideas ?

Comment: Are we talking about wpf or wp7 here? (the problem is not the same in these two)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define it somewhere. Usually, this is in App.xaml as follows:

```
<Application ...
             xmlns:sys=clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <sys:String x:Key="AppName">My Application Title</sys:String>
    ...
```